# fork() and Binary tree creation

Tags: c, fork, binary-tree

How binary tree will be created for following code ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
   fork();
   fork() && fork() || fork();
   fork();

   printf("forked\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Basically i am not able to solve logical operator conditions .For unconditional fork() statements it can easily be done but what about above code .
For reference here is the link 
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fork-and-binary-tree/

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   fork(); /* A */
   ( fork()  /* B */ &&
   fork()  /* C */ ) || /* B and C are grouped according to precedence */
   fork(); /* D */
   fork(); /* E */

   printf("forked\n");
   return 0;
}
```

- There are 5 fork calls(A,B,C,D,E).
- The program starts with a main thread(m).
- When fork is executed a new child process will be created. (c)

So according to the diagram shown, each node will **ALWAYS** have 2 childs nodes.

- The left node is always the creating process(m)
- right node is the child process.

> “On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child.”

Lets look at fork B.
the parent process(m) will return a non-negetive pid and child process(c1) returns 0.

- Therefore, the parent process  executes **fork C**, but skips **fork
  D** due to [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

  `(1234 && 4392) || fork()`
- The newly created  child process skips **fork C** and executes **fork
  D** for above mentioned reason.

  `(0 && fork() ) || fork()`

[image]